# Can you edit resx files with Visual Web Developer?

Tags: visual-studio, resx, visual-studio-express, visual-web-developer

Simple question, but I am not allowed to install this program at work to test it out.  Does it work just like Visual Studio for editing resx files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seemingly... [MSDN Article about editing Resx in VWD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247246.aspx)